# How to trigger a flow when a document is pasted in a synced sharepoint folder?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I want to trigger a flow whenever a file is added to a Sharepoint folder.

When using the "When a file is created in a folder" trigger, the flow is triggered if I upload a new file from the Sharepoint Web UI or if I save a new file into the synced folder on my computer.

But if I copy/paste or move a file from my computer's filesystem to the Sharepoint synced folder, the flow isn't triggered.

Comment: Do you have any follow-up questions?

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior and it is by design it seems.

> Files uploaded to SharePoint have a modification date of today
> and the document that I copied locally and Synced to
> SharePoint kept their original date. ...
>
> A lot of the Flow technology
> depending on web hooks and one of the things webhooks does is use a
> last change token. This is to ensure that you only pickup changes
> since a certain date.
>
> ... make sure that you upload document to SharePoint rather than
> synchronising document to SharePoint.

[Uploading documents to SharePoint using OneDrive/Sync and Microsoft Flow ignores these](https://veenstra.me.uk/2018/09/19/uploading-documents-to-sharepoint-using-onedrive-sync-and-microsoft-flow-ignores-these/)

Author in comment:

> I’ve not found a solution for this yet. The only real option at the moment is to use a recurring flow.